# Removing outer brackets from an array

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
arr = Array.new
arr = [ "172" , "173"]
arr = arr.join(" , " )   
puts arr
```

The output is 172, 173, however, I want the output to look like "172", "173".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a bit premature. Where have you searched for solutions? What else did you try? As is, it looks like you tried one thing and then asked. Please read "[ask]". Read through the String documentation for [`%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-25) and Kernel's [`format`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-format).

Answer (score 3):

Roughly:

```
arr.collect(&:inspect).join(', ')
```

As a note, `Array.new` is better expressed as `[]` which is simply an empty array. The only reason to use `Array.new` is if you're specifying arguments to it.

Comment: This just replaces the `join` portion of one line, so I hope that much is clear.

Comment: HI, for some reason, I am getting the below output: "\"172\", \"173\"" Please help !!

Comment: @me24hour That's what the string will look like with `inspect`, but if you print it using `puts` the extra escaping will go away.

Comment: but the encloses the string using double-quotes. I need single quotes. :(

Comment: @Surya Ruby's `inspect` will always use double quotes. If you need single quotes you might be able to get away with `string.tr('"', "'")` or you may need to do additional escaping if you need `'` to become `\'`.